# dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid, how does it work?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid

I have a few questions about dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid:

1. How to get rowindexes of the selected row?
2. How to remove a row by its rowIndex?
3. How do I check if a row is selected or not?

I have tried `removeSelectedRows()` and `rowRemoved(inRowIndex)`, but I couldn't make them work; my cpu usage started growing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1&2 :

```
var items = lstNotes.selection.getSelected();
                    if (items.length) {
                        dojo.forEach(items, function(selectedItem) {
                            if (selectedItem !== null) {
                                notesStore.deleteItem(selectedItem);
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

3: `dijit.byId('grid').selection.selected[rowIndex] // returns true or fals`